# Ada test if directory exist in gpr file

Tags: ada

I have a `project.gpr` used by 5 projects containing this :

```
MyProject_Source_Dirs := 
{
  external ("HOME") & "/project2/src/**",
  external ("HOME") & "/project3/src/**",
  "./src/**",
  "./stub/**"
}
for Source_Dirs use MyProject_Source_Dirs;
```

When I build my project I have following error :

> "./stub" is not a valid directory

This gpr file is used for 5 different projects. 2 of theses projects have no directory named "stub". Is there a way to check if directory exists ?

Comment: You might try [_Setting the --create-missing-dirs option in a gprbuild file_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46520424/230513).

Comment: I've try but my company has an old GPR, this option is not recognised.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect the version requirement and any relevant context, e.g. a build script that might be able to handle the problem.

Comment: I have never seen this syntax before `MyProject_Source_Dirs := { ... }` for GPR files. The closest thing to this is inside the GNAT docs, in the section describing the GPR file syntax principles `name        ::= simple_name { . simple_name }`

Comment: @trashgod I've on the latest version of GNAT Pro/GNAT Studio and I have `for Create_Missing_Dirs use "True";` at the top of my gpr file, but I still have the same issue as the OP. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You might experiment with this [example](https://github.com/trashgod/roots).